# ExtJS Grid Pagination Not Working

Tags: java, javascript, extjs

I am new to extjs and trying to get the grid pagination working on for a project.

Can anyone tell me if there is an online tutorial to setup pagination for extjs grid? I am getting the records for the first page but no on clicking the next button.

It would be great if some one can code or specify what code changes are required to get the next set of results.

Any help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: Is there a particular reason this is tagged as Java?

Comment: It is very  helpful when you use Firebug or other developer console to check what exactly is being sent to the server-side, and what is returning back from server. This seems to me a server-side issue, where you need to use an offset parameter to make the proper SQL database query...

Comment: @vcsjones: I suppose the server-side language is Java - and I suppose the issue is really a server-side one... more exactly: how to build the SQL query to get the correct "page" of records.

Comment: Actually the server side code is in java. I have a proper SQL that fetch correct # of records only issue is its not getting results after I click "next" button. I also notice that my loadstore contains parameter those are not getting passed on next ....Any idea how I can store those parameters

Comment: Please don't repost your questions.

Answer (score 1):

For an example check out http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/paging.html

The service that example uses can be seen here:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-browse-remote.php?&page=3&start=100&limit=50&sort=lastpost&dir=DESC

Note that Ext JS Paging Toolbar adds the page, start, limit and sort params to the URL.

Your java code will need to reference these and use them in your SQL query.

A Spring controller might have something like this which will allow you to access the query params later in the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listTopics", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listTopics(
        @RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer start
        @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer limit
        ) {
```

...
}

Also see this full java example with working demo:
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/02/extjs-grid-cell-editing-tutorial-2.html